# Pass button click event to actionPerformed on key press

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, keylistener, keyevent

I'm working on a Java assignment that has to be done using AWT.  I want a button to trigger by pushing the enter key while the button is in focus.  I figured out how to do this in Swing with the doClick() method, but this doesn't seem to work in AWT.  So far I'm trying this:

```
button.addActionListener(this); // Passes value from a TextBox to actionPerformed() 

button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
              actionPerformed(null);
         }
    } 
});

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
     try {  
          if (e.getSource() == button) {
               // Stuff I want to happen
          } else if (e.getSource() == anotherButton) {
               // Other Stuff
          } else {     //third button
               // More stuff
          }
     } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
          // Null argument in keyPressed triggers this
          // catches empty string exception from TextBox
     }
 }
```

As I mentioned with the comments, the null argument will trigger the catch.  Does anyone have any idea what that argument might be for the button press or perhaps an altogether easier way to go about this?  Thanks.

Edit - clarification: actionPerformed() does one of three things with input from a TextBox depending on which of three buttons is clicked.  The try/catch is to catch empty string/format exceptions.

Comment: `... that has to be done using AWT.` ack! I feel sorry for you. :(

Comment: It's generally not good practice to rely on exception handling to trigger events / use them as if they were conditionals.

Comment: Might just be me but I would only have `if`'s and `else if`'s in my `actionPerformed` (or similar) methods. If somehow your `actionPerformed` gets called from a component you haven't set conditionals for, just ignore it.

Comment: In other words; if the source was `button`, call `onButtonPress()`, if it wasn't, just ignore it. If you have another button called `button2`, add `} else if(source == button2) {` to your `actionPerformed`.

Comment: I would never have a `catch` or an `else` in an `actionPerformed`.

Comment: Sorry for the comment-dump, but you'd also be better off not calling `actionPerformed` directly. Delegate each of `actionPerformed` and `keyPressed` to methods that define what should happen when the button is pressed, for example if the button is a 'close' button, call 'onClose()` or if it's a submit button, call something like `submit()`. Up to you. :)

Comment: I'm sure you can manage without the `try catch`. Post your `actionPerformed` code.

Comment: Consider this approach: http://goo.gl/Khp9T

Comment: Hey yo, if it works would be cool if you could accept answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always have a method called something like `onButtonPress()`, which your `actionPerformed` can call, as well as your `keyPressed`.

```
  button.addActionListener(this);

    button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
              onButtonPress();
         }
    } 
 });

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button){
       onButtonPress();
    } 
 }

private void onButtonPress(){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I hadn't considered this but I would end up having to break up all the conditionals in my actionPerformed() method which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: So you *do* want to have conditionals / `if-else`'s in your `actionPerformed`?

Comment: how to check the key press is `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` in actionPerformed?