# What is wrong with my Key Listener? It does not go into key pressed at all

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

```
public class Maze extends JPanel
{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int previousX = x;
    int previousY = y;

    public Maze()
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        addKeyListener(new ArrowListener());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.fillRect(previousX, previousY, 10, 10);
        page.setColor(Color.magenta);
        page.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);

    }

    private class ArrowListener implements KeyListener
    {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println("pressed");
            previousX = x;
            previousY = y;

            switch(event.getKeyCode())
            {

            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                if(y >= 0)
                    y--;
                System.out.println("up");
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                if(y <= 100)
                    y++;
                System.out.println("Down");
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                if(x >= 0)
                    x--;
                System.out.println("Left");
                break;

            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                if(x <= 100)
                    x++;
                System.out.println("Right");


            }
            repaint();
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event){}

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event){}

    }
}
```

The println lines do not print at all, indicating it doesn't even go into the keyPressed method. What am I doing wrong? All it is supposed to do is move a rect around the screen.

Comment: are you looking at java console?

Comment: It works for me.  Edit your question and show the code you’ve written which adds a `Maze` to a window or applet.

Comment: Something else may be stealing the focus, perhaps a JButton or a text component such as a JTextField. This is one reason to try to avoid keylisteners and instead use Key Bindings.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013034/pass-button-click-event-to-actionperformed-on-key-press

Comment: If you spend a few minutes search for "key listener doesn't work", you'll find that in most cases, it's a focus related issue, which is most commonly solved by using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). As you can see from the responses you're getting, it can also be some what random at times

Answer (score 2):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    static Maze m = new Maze();
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(m);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I wrote this Main class quickly and tested your code. It worked for me.

Comment: setSize() and pack() are mutually exclusive. Only need one or the other.